# Error while dialing /dns/telemetry... error: Other(A(Handshake(Io(Kind(UnexpectedEof))))) - not just Timeout

Tags: substrate-node-template

I have been having the same issue all day where the following commands return the subsequent types of telemetry errors.

```
./target/release/node-template \
  --base-path /tmp/node01 \
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
  --port 30333 \
  --ws-port 9945 \
  --rpc-port 9933 \
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
  --validator \
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name MyNode01 \
  --password-interactive
```

```
2022-10-13 19:20:51 ❌ Error while dialing /dns/telemetry.polkadot.io/tcp/443/x-parity-wss/%2Fsubmit%2F: Custom { kind: Other, error: Timeout }   
2022-10-13 19:21:16 ❌ Error while dialing /dns/telemetry.polkadot.io/tcp/443/x-parity-wss/%2Fsubmit%2F: Custom { kind: Other, error: Other(A(Handshake(Io(Kind(UnexpectedEof))))) }
```

The only things that I changed from the node-template are the following;

- `pub const EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT = 0`
- setting all initial balances to 0
- limiting the `initial_authorities` and `endowed_accounts` to just Alice
- adding local keys to add as `aura` and `grandpa` authorities

It was working fine last night, and although I did play around with `ChainType::Live` since then, I am having issues regardless of any `ChainType`. /tmp/* have been purged. Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly please?

Comment: I think this is okay. Telemetry will refuse your connection sometimes. There is no harm to your chain.

Comment: I see, it just felt odd I continue to get the same telemtry error for almost 24 hours... What would be the best way to look up more details on `error: Other(A(Handshake(Io(Kind(UnexpectedEof)))))`?

Comment: `RUST_LOG=sc_telemetry`, I don't remember if it is `sc_telemetry`, but something like that.